# jQuery dynamic element is created but not able to get the handle to dynamic elements

Tags: jquery

In the below code, I am looping through each XML and creating dynamic content.

```
$('#instDiv').append( "<div><b>" + 
$(this).attr('institute') + "</b></div>" + 
"<div>Type: " + $(this).find('type').text() + 
"</div>" + "<div>Name:</div>" + 
"<div onClick=\"showDiv('inst"+idCounter+"');\"><b>" + $(this).find('RM').text() + 
"</b></div>" + "<span id=\"inst"+idCounter+"\" >" + 
"<table><tr><td rowspan=3><img height=50 width=40 src='imgurl'></img></td><td>Phone#: " + $(this).find('ph').text() + "</td></tr>" + 
"<tr><td>Email: " + $(this).find('mail').text() + 
"</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>Location: " + $(this).find('loc').text() + 
"</td></tr></table></span>" );
```

Calling a `showDiv` function on click of the name. Creating a span with id as inst & counter.

So for the first element, the id would be `inst0`.

The `showDiv` function code is shown below.

```
function showDiv(divID) {
 alert(divID);
 alert($('#instDiv').html());
 alert($(divID).length);
 $(divID).toggle(); 
}
```

In the above code, I am able to get the `divID` value & `innerHTML` of `instDiv` also printing the span with the same id.

But, when I try to print that `divID` length, its returning **0**. Which means, there is no element with that id. In our example the id is `inst0`. But, this is present in `instDiv` innerHTML.

How can I get the access to that element. I need to toggle the display on click of the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery selector should be `#inst0` rather than just `inst0` if you are selecting by the ID attribute, so prepend a hash/pound symbol like this:

```
function showDiv(divID) {
   alert($('#' + divID).length);
   $('#' + divID).toggle(); 
}
```